# c++ define vector in separate function

Tags: c++

I want to define a vector with static content in a function that might be used by multiple programs. However I am facing some problems.

The main.cpp looked like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/assign/std/vector.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::assign;

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {

  vector< int > v;
  v +=   3,5,1;

  for (int i=0; i<v.size(); i++) {
   cout << "v: " << i << " " << v[i] << endl;
  }
}
```

This works and I get as an output:

```
v: 0 3
v: 1 5
v: 2 1
```

However if I try to put the vector definition into a separate file it does not work.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "vector_test.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {

  vector< int > v;

  for (int i=0; i<v.size(); i++) {
    cout << "v: " << i << " " << v[i] << endl;
  }
}
```

vector_test.hpp:

```
#include <boost/assign/std/vector.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::assign;


static std::vector<int> v;
v +=   3,5,1;
```

Trying to compile this gives me an error:

```
'v' does not name a type
```

and the qt creator also tells me:

```
expected a declaration
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What type is `vector`? It is important to know that.

Comment: Please post the code that doesn't work, otherwise we can't help you. Also, are you using Boost.assign? `v += 3,5,1` would require that or a similar library.

Comment: @juanchopanza: What exactly do you mean with type? I need to store integers, so I defined it as in the question with `vector<int>`. Does that help?

Comment: What is the `vector` you are using? What library did you get it from and where is the documentation. One needs to know, in order to suggest ways to initialize it etc.

Comment: @interjay, yes sorry I am using `boost::assign`.

Comment: @juanchopanza: the vector is from `std::vector`. As I wrote, if I use it in the main.cpp it works fine but I cannot get it working from a different function.

Comment: Please re-edit your question, clearly described,Thanks

Comment: it's spelled "separate".

Comment: One question I do have. Why do I get all the down votes for this question. Ok some pieces of information were missing, but I supplied them. I am no c++ crack and I could not find the answer to this question anywhere else. Perhaps someone can help me here so I do not bother people again in the future doing the same mistake.

Comment: One thing is that because of this line: `v += 3,5,1;` it was hard to know what `vector` you were talking about and that makes it hard to answer. That line makes no sense without `boost::assign`, and you hadn't mentioned anything about that. If you had posted an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then things might have gone better.

Comment: @juanchopanza, thanks for the hint. For me it was "absolutely clear", but then I have my head buried in this code for a while ;). Anyway, most important it works now :)

Comment: I think going through the exercise of creating an MCVE is very important. For example, you would have seen that `v += 3,5,1;` doesn't just work unless you use a 3rd party library (boost), you'd narrow down what is causing the error and might even be able to fix it yourself. Worst case you provide enough information that someone with experience can give you a quick solution.

Comment: I will definitely keep this in mind for my next issue. Thanks for the patience and the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to have a function returning a reference to a static instance:

```
const std::vector<int>& get_magic_vector()
{
  static std::vector<int> v{3, 5, 1};
  return v;
}
```

Then

```
for (auto i : get_magic_vector())
  std::cout << i << " ";
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, although I had to rewrite it a little to this: `const std::vector<int>& get_magic_vector()
{
static std::vector<int> v;
v+=3, 5, 1;
return v;
}`

Comment: @red_tiger OK, that must mean you don't have C++11 support.

Answer (score 0):

In your other files you must say that the variable exists but is defined in another file. That is, in otherFile.cpp you place the following line at file scope:

```
 extern std::vector<int> v;
```